# Form submit button is not working sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have developed a quiz module in which whenever the user clicks on `submit` button, the button gets `disabled` and then redirected to next question.

Now the problem is sometimes the `submit` button doesn't respond for about 4-5 or more clicks and then suddenly submits the form which results in skipping of 4-5 questions. Have tried using `document.form.submit` and even `jQuery('#question_form').submit()`. But still few users report the same problem.

I am unable to create the same scenario for myself.

In my view page I have:

```
   <form id="question_form" style="text-align:center;" name="question_form" method="post" action="/exam/259/calc_current_score?name=question" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- some fields to be submitted -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="changeButtonText(event,this.form);" name="submit_button" id="submit_button" class="exam-btn-primary">

    </form>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeButtonText(e,form){

//if validation is true then it submits the form like this
        error_notification.style.display="none";
        form.submit();
        jQuery('#submit_button').css({'background-color':'#C3CACD'});
        form.submit_button.disabled=true;
        return true;

//else if the validation fails then 'submit button' is not disabled
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    </script>
```

So, the main problem is that even when the user clicks on the submit button after selecting an option neither the form gets submitted (which would eventually redirect to the next page) nor the button gets `disabled` (also the color of the button changes when validations are successful) so they keep clicking and this mostly happens in `Google Chrome`. I don't know that is it because of slow net connection or the resources are taking longer time to load.

Users report that sometimes they have to click multiple number of times in order to submit the question's answer, and whenever they click multiple number of times the questions get skipped. For example if they click `x` times on `submit button` they move forward by `x` questions and they are unable to score because of that.

Comment: Please post your code.What you have tried unless we can't answer you?

Comment: 1. do you call event.preventDefault after a click is triggered and just after that submitting the form? 2. Are you using turbolinks? is there a change that the click event is triggered more than once?

Comment: may be when the user clicks the button for the first time the form is submitting and the user doesn't know about it and keeps clicking. try alerting before the submit to know whether submit is working or not

Comment: @vladCovaliov when the user clicks on 'submit button' and if the validation is successful the button is disabled, so I feel there's no way a user can click on the button twice and then the page redirects to the next question otherwise the user remains on the same page.

Comment: disabling the button might be the actual cause.

Comment: Finally replaced the submit button with a 'div' tag styled to look like a button. This solved my problem. There's some weird problem with the submit button which once in a while stops working. So had to replace the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all because of `jQuery` being blocked on windows XP machines. But still I removed the `submit` tag and used a `div` tag as a button and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar problem. In my case, browser on the Android tablet sometimes ran `ontouch` event and `onclick` event on a single tap. It occurred when user taps any other place quickly after tapping the submit button. The problem was solved when calling `preventDefault();` at both `ontouch` and `onclick`. How about checking what kind of a browser and a terminal your users are using?

ADD:

OK, your actual problem is "a submit button is clicked even if it is disabled", isn't it?

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeButtonText(e,form){
        form.submit_button.disabled=true;

//if validation is true then it submits the form like this
        error_notification.style.display="none";
        jQuery('#submit_button').css({'background-color':'#C3CACD'});
        form.submit();

//else if the validation fails then 'submit button' is not disabled
        form.submit_button.disabled=true;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Users are using browsers on desktop. When I asked them they said that initially the button didnt respond to any of the clicks but when it responded they had skipped many questions as if each click was submitting the form without redirecting to next page.

Comment: Is your validation code at the server? In this case, users can do next click earlier than the response of validation, because of the time lag between a client and a server.

Comment: No javascript validation code is present on the same page like whether the user has selected an option or not.